# Can't Remove Empty Custom Toolbar Under Add-ins tab

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, toolbar

After messing around in Excel for a while, I have found out that a new toolbar called "Custom Toolbars" containing nothing showing under "Add-ins" tab as shown as the screenshot below.

[image]

Although I can remove it by right clicking it and select "delete custom toolbar", but this empty custom toolbar seems to rebuild itself and shows up every time I open Excel.

How can I deal with it?

Comment: most probably it isn't a virus. Can be a bug, or a workbook (maybe hidden) or module have something wrong in it. Go to File - options - add-ins (at least in 2010, I think it's similar in 2013 too), and check them, if you can't find any suspicious try to disable all of them to see the problem disappears.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, caused by the Team Foundation Add-in. Tools --> Options --> Add-Ins, Manage COM Add-ins and disabled it there did the trick for me

Answer (score 0):

Most probably it isn't a virus.

Worst case it can be a bug.

Or it can be caused by a workbook (maybe hidden) or module having something wrong in it.

- Go to "File - options - add-ins" (at least in 2010, I think it's similar in 2013 too), and check them.
- If you can't find any suspicious try to disable all of them to see whether the problem disappears.
- If disabling all the add-ins help then just enable one by one and check the issue to find the one causing the issue.